# Solr parent child update version conflict

Tags: solr

I have an issue with an optimistic update for a Solr core. The core has been created as a parent child structure with a one to many relationship. I am trying to update an existing document, but every time I try the update fails on a version conflict with the message;

```
{"msg":"version conflict for ZZFFG-BB8F-XXXX-8BCE-TYGSFSGHGHHH
 expected=1525961521901862912 actual=-1","code":409}}
```

However the version of the document I am trying to update is identical to the version of the document I am posting, but for some reason, it is not being recognised. Here is the document I am posting to the core;

```
{
  "Content_Type": "parentDocument",
  "Username": "xxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx",
  "Email": "pp@test-europe.com",
  "First Name": "XXXXXX",
  "ParentContactId": "15448",
  "Last Activity Date": "2007-10-10 10:49:14.0",
  "Id": "ZZFFG-BB8F-XXXX-8BCE-TYGSFSGHGHHH",
  "Surname": "YYYYYYYYYYY",
  "_version_": 1525961521901862912,
  _childDocuments_" [
    { 
      "ChildContactId": "15448",
      "Content_Type": "childDocument",
      "Postcode": "GP7 8PT",
      "Telephone": "01000 000000",
      "Town": "TestVille",
      "Dealer Number": "111",
      "ParentCentreId": "1234",
      "Name": "Testville Test"
    }
  ]
}'
```

As you can see the version I am posting is identical to the expected version specified in the error message - 1525961521901862912. The update document listed above is fetched from the core altered and then posted back, which is the accepted method. This method works on other cores, although these do not have a nested parent child structure. I have tried removing the versioning check by setting the version id to 0, but this results in a new record being created, rather than an update. I have also tried adding the 'dedup update processor' which should prevent duplicates with the same signature field being created but this has no effect. As a last resort I even recreated the core, but the problem persists. The data-config is included below. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
                driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
                url="sqlserver://localhost"   
                user="Dev" 
                password="XXXXXXXXXX"/>
    <document>
        <entity 
            name="User"  
            pk="Id"
            query="SELECT 'parentDocument' as 'Content_Type',
                  C.[Contact_id] as 'ParentContactId', S.[UserId] As Id, 
                  S. [UserName], S.[LastActivityDate],  C.[Contact_id], 
                  C.[ForeName], C.[Surname], C.[Email]
                  FROM [Table1] as S
                  inner join .[Table2] as P on 
                  S.[UserName] = P.[User_Name]
                  inner join [Table3] as C on 
                  P.[Contact_id] = C.[Contact_id]
                  where (C.[Email] is not null and len(C.[Email])> 0)">
           <field column="Content_Type" name="Content_Type"/>
           <field column="ParentContactId" name="ParentContactId"/>
           <field column="Id" name="Id"/>
           <field column="UserName" name="Username"/>   
           <field column="LastActivityDate" name="Last Activity Date"/>   
           <field column="Contact_id" name="ContactId"/>   
           <field column="ForeName" name="First Name"/>   
           <field column="Surname" name="Surname"/>   
           <field column="Email" name="Email"/>
           <entity 
                name="Centre"   
                pk="ChildContactId, Centre_id"
                query="SELECT 'childDocument' as 'Content_Type',
                   CC.[Contact_id] as 'ChildContactId', CC.[Contact_id], 
                   CenT.[Name], CenT.[Telephone], 
                   Cen.[Centre_id] as 'ParentCentreId', 
                   Cen.[Centre_id], Cen.[Dealer_No], Ad.[Town], 
                   Ad.[Post_code]
                   From [Table4] CC
                   inner join [Table5] as CenT on
                   CC.Centre_id = CenT.Centre_id
                   inner join [Table6] as Cen on 
                   CenT.Centre_id = Cen.Centre_id
                   inner join [Table7] as Ad on 
                   Cen.[Address_id] = Ad.[Address_id]
                   where CC.[Contact_id] = ${User.Contact_id}"
                child="true">
                <field column="Content_Type" name="Content_Type"/>
                <field column="ChildContactId" name="ChildContactId"/>
                <field column="Contact_id" name="ContactId"/> 
                <field column="Name" name="Name"/>
                <field column="Telephone" name="Telephone"/>
                <field column="ParentCentreId" name="ParentCentreId"/>
                <field column="Centre_id" name="Centreid"/>
                <field column="Dealer_No" name="Dealer Number"/>
                <field column="Town" name="Town"/>
                <field column="Post_code" name="Postcode"/>     
            </entity>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Comment: Do you know where that -1 is coming from in the error response?

Comment: Its coming back in the response string from the Solr server. Solr does not seem to recognise the actual version number being posted to it. IIRC it always returns -1 regardless of what you pass through.

Comment: The -1 generally means Solr couldn't find a document with that version. If you're using some automated process to send the updates to Solr, try sending one of the documents yourself by hand on the Solr admin UI. Select your core name, then click the Documents link and you'll be at the page where you can do that.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I am getting the same response through the Solr Admin, although it doesn't always return -1 as the actual, sometimes I get a different unrelated version. Examples below.

Comment: Status: error

Error: Conflict

Error:{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 409,
    "QTime": 2
  },
  "error": {
    "msg": "version conflict for BDFB3F36-974F-489E-AE89-389816C02687 expected=1526235536232022000 actual=-1",
    "code": 409
  }
}

Comment: Status: error

Error: Conflict

Error:{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 409,
    "QTime": 1
  },
  "error": {
    "msg": "version conflict for 2BC30E0E-A8CF-4CF3-8BCE-7920DAEBC72E expected=1526235536234119100 actual=-1526234987968331776",
    "code": 409
  }
}

Comment: I am extracting these from a query and pushing them straight into the document update on the solr admin.

Comment: Found a work round for this. First fetch the copy of the document. Delete the parent document from the core. Then you have to delete the children. Update the document and insert it back into the core. If you don't delete the children these end up added to the new parent and you have twice as many children. You also have to set the version to zero before you insert. The delete has to be a delete by query because deleting by Id has no effect. Thank you TMBT for your input, pointing me towards the document link was a great help.